# How to replace specific array string values with corresponding numbers in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an array with some repeating string values. How to replace these string values (as a whole, because some words are repeated in others strings) with corresponding specific numeric values, as bellow?

```
deloc        = 1
foarte puţin = 2
mediu        = 3
mult         = 4
foarte mult  = 5
```

This is the array (example):

```
array = (
    "tensionat"     => "mediu",
    "trist"         => "mult",
    "melancolic"    => "deloc",
    "fara_speranta" => "foarte puțin",
    "nefolositor"]  => "deloc",
    "ingrijorat"    => "foarte mult",
    "amarat"        => "deloc",
    "anxios"        => "mediu"
);
```

How can this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```php
$data = array (
    "tensionat"     => "mediu",
    "trist"         => "mult",
    "melancolic"    => "deloc",
    "fara_speranta" => "foarte puțin",
    "nefolositor"   => "deloc",
    "ingrijorat"    => "foarte mult",
    "amarat"        => "deloc",
    "anxios"        => "mediu"
);

$repl = array (
    'deloc'        => 1,
    'foarte puţin' => 2,
    'mediu'        => 3,
    'mult'         => 4,
    'foarte mult'  => 5,
);

$result = array ();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = !empty($repl[$value]) ? $repl[$value] : $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [tensionat] => 3
    [trist] => 4
    [melancolic] => 1
    [fara_speranta] => foarte puțin
    [nefolositor] => 1
    [ingrijorat] => 5
    [amarat] => 1
    [anxios] => 3
)
```

Comment: Note, `foarte puţin` !== `foarte puțin`.

Comment: Or in one line: `$result = array_map(fn($v) => $repl[$v] ?? false ?: $v, $data);`

Comment: @pilan, I got this error: `syntax error, unexpected '=>'`. What this can be?

Comment: Thank you, @IhorVyspiansky! But how to solve the `[fara_speranta] => foarte puțin`? Insteed of `foarte puțin` I need `2`.

Comment: Can you use `"fara_speranta" => "foarte puţin",` instead of `"fara_speranta" => "foarte puțin",` or `'foarte puțin' => 2,` instead of `'foarte puţin' => 2,`? `foarte puţin` is NOT equal to `foarte puțin`! Due to these both `ţ` and `ț` are different.

Comment: Why do you use the different strings?

Comment: Good question! Only today I realized that the two "ț" are not identical, so I replaced one of them and now the code (from [3v4l.org/BfM2k](http://3v4l.org/BfM2k)) is working as expected. Thank you very much!!!